# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne') NODEJS API

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, express, mongoose

estoy teniendo problemas al hacer el login de mi api con jwt.
El tema es el siguiente este seria mi controlador:

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({'email': req.email})
    console.log(user)
    
    if(!user){
      handleHttpError(res, "USER_NOT_EXISTS", 404);
      return
    }
    const hashPassword = user.get('password');

    const check = await compare(req.password, hashPassword)

    if(!check){
      handleHttpError(res, "PASSWORD_INVALID", 401);
      return
    }

    const data = {
      token: await tokenSign(user),
      user
    }

    res.send({data})


  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
    handleHttpError(res, "ERROR_LOGIN_USER")
  }
```

el problema esta en que cuando hago una peticion post en postman me arroja este error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')**

y no se como solucionarlo, busque por varios lugares y no encontré la solución.
Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Parece que no hubieras usado "require" del modelo `User`... Si si hiciste require, pero no funciona, probablemente el error este en el archivo user

Comment: gracias por la respuesta después de mirar bien el código tenia un error el archivo .env de las variables de entorno lo tenia dentro de la carpeta src por lo tanto no me tomaba la base de datos. ya pude solucionar el problema muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mirar bien el código tenia un error:

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const params = req.body

// Y EN USER TENIA OTRO ERROR YA QUE ESTABA BUSCANDO EL EMAIL COMO {"email": paramas,email}
    const user = await User.findOne({email: params.email})
    console.log(user)
    console.log(params)

    if(!user){
      handleHttpError(res, "El usuario no existe.", 404);
      return
    }
//ACA TENIA UN ERROR AL CONSEGUIR EL HASHPASSWORD.
    const hashPassword = user.get('password');

    const check = await compare(params.password, hashPassword)

    if(!check){
      handleHttpError(res, "Password incorrecta.", 401);
      return
    }

    const data = {
      token: await tokenSign(user),
      user
    }

    res.send({data})


  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
    handleHttpError(res, "Error al logear.")
  }

}
```

el archivo .env de las variables de entorno lo tenia dentro de la carpeta src por lo tanto no me tomaba el nombre de la base de datos por lo tanto a la hora de hacer la busqueda findOne me devolvia null.
Eso es todo lo que hice. Saludos.

Comment: Hola lauta10ma, sería bueno que editarás tu respuesta, describiendo cual era el error y como lo solucionaste, de esa forma puedes estar ayudando a otros, gracias de antemano!!!

Comment: ya estaria. Saludos-

Comment: Grande Maestro!!!